# Why does the bootstrapped correlation revolve around zero while the original correlation $\approx 0.52$?

Tags: r, time-series, bootstrap

I have two data series containing 132 log-returns. One is for EURUSD, the other is for NZDUSD. The `head()` function shows you how some of the data looks. The correlation coefficient between the two, as calculated by `cor()` is $0.5178912$.

To get a better sense of the correlation coefficient I bootstrap it by running `cor()` 1000 times on different 132 long samples. I run this in a loop and update `euro.nzd.corr` on every iteration. This is the R code I'm using:

```
head(euro)
[1] -0.001257862 -0.011637970  0.002428757  0.003602590 -0.003457319 -0.002012728
head(nzd)
[1]  0.008773255 -0.007744927  0.005498693  0.005642524 -0.000896363  0.003449576
cor(euro,nzd)
[1] 0.5178912
euro.nzd.corr <- numeric(1000)
for(i in 1:1000){
euro.nzd.corr[i] = cor(euro[sample(132,132,replace=TRUE)],nzd[sample(132,132,replace=TRUE)])
}
plot(density(euro.nzd.corr), lwd=3, col="steelblue")
```

Once I have the data, I plot the density chart, and get this:

[image: density]

Bootstrapped data has mean $\approx 0$ and mostly spreads between $-0.3$ and $0.3$. Where has the initial `cor()` result of $0.5178912$ gone? What am I to make of this? That it is better to conclude the two variables are uncorrelated versus correlated with a coefficient of $\approx 0.52$? Have I made any coding mistakes, or is the applied methodology simply flawed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is an obvious reason for that: You are sampling from both series separately, thus destroying any correlation. You probably want to sample pairs, not observations in each series, e.g.

```
index <- sample(132,132, replace=TRUE)
euro.nzd.corr[i] = cor(euro[index], nzd[index])
```

Fixing your code should allow you to recover a distribution centered on .5 but you might want to look up some literature before relying on these inferences as there are some niceties about bootstrapping correlations. As @NickCox pointed out, the fact that both set of observations are times series also creates further difficulties. You should be able to find a lot of material on all that.

Comment: Add that bootstrapping time series is deeply problematic.

Comment: +1, Ninja'd me as well (I was up to "It looks to me like your bootstrap function is not respecting the paired-ness of the two currency objects")

Comment: @NickCox Good point, I edited my answer to highlight it.

Comment: There is a nice symmetry here. My initial comment was purely about time series; I didn't spot the point you caught on separate sampling.

Comment: +1, however (setting aside @NickCox's good point about time-series), I wouldn't necessarily say that sampling from 2 vectors separately is a mistake. I would say the mistake is in understanding / interpretation. Bootstrapping by sampling from 2 vectors separately can be a perfectly good way to estimate the null sampling distribution.